# Change Direction of Tween

Tags: javascript, easeljs, tweenjs

Using tweenJS, I setup a rectangle to slowly shrink, however, it shrinks from the bottom up and instead I'd like it to go from top down. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
var bar1 = new createjs.Shape();
bar1.graphics.beginFill('black');
stage.addChild(bar1);
var bar1Command = bar1.graphics.drawRect(50, 50, 10, 130).command;
var tween1 = createjs.Tween.get(bar1Command, { loop: true }).to({ h: 0 }, 5000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ra10x0d3/1/

Thank you!!

Comment: Just set the original height to 0 and the final one to 130: https://jsfiddle.net/14rac9bu/

Comment: that's the direction I'd like it to go in, but is there a way to start with the full bar and have shrink down to nothing in that direction?

Comment: Oh, I see. Then, you need to animate the height as well as the top position: https://jsfiddle.net/voeoohro/

Comment: perfect, thank you!